# Loading custom fonts with webfont.js

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to use some 5 custom fonts.

I use webfont.js library so that I can time my initialisation the way I want to.

However, I notice that I have an intermittent issue, whereby webfont.js will fail loading all 5 fonts 75% of the time. If I ignore the error (inactive handler) and just resume loading my site I can see all custom fonts fine.

This is annoying because webfont.js takes around 4 seconds to raise the inactive event and so the user just sees the blank page while this is happening.

How do I fix (or at least debug) this?

This is my setup (util.js):

```
var mutexFontsLoaded = $.Callbacks("memory once");
WebFontConfig = {
  custom: {
    families: ['Chennai-Regular', 'Chennai-Light', 'Chennai-Bold', 'Quicksand-Bold', 'Segoe-Print'],
    urls: ['css/fonts.css']
  },
  loading: function () { console.log("Loading fonts.."); },
  active: function () { mutexFontsLoaded.fire(); },
  fontinactive: function (font, fvd) { console.log("Could'nt load " + font + " font"); },
  inactive: function () { console.log("All fonts failed loading..\n\rTrying to load site anyway.."); mutexFontsLoaded.fire(); }
};
```

Followed by the Web Font Loader library - 1.5.1

Then in my main script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    mutexFontsLoaded.add(function()
    {
        application.init();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging the webfont.js library from google's CDN made me see the issue.

Webfont.js injects a `<span>` with a test string into the `<body>` DOM element. It then sets the custom font on this span and repeatedly calculates width of the `<span>` to test for any changes. If it captures a change then it assumes the custom font has loaded. If no change is detected within a timeout then it signals failure.

In my case `<body>` element was hidden with `display: none;` because I only wanted to show the page once I knew all the elements are downloaded. Because of this the injected `<span>` never changed its calculated width.

Finally fixed!

Comment: How did you debug webfont.js?  I can't find a non-minified version.